# twitter share button with dynamic url through JS

Tags: javascript, twitter, share

I am getting a headache getting this to work. I managed to do it with fb, but twitter doesn't work.

I made a js function that takes the html path of a page with a few other parameters, and I just want to use that function instead of manually writing the url. Problem is, twitter stops at the text, and doesn't write the url given by "htmlpath".

{
        window.open("http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=An%20Awesome%20Link&url=" + htmlpath);
        }

Answer (score 0):

If I would hazard a guess, it would be that you need to prepend the protocol (most likely `http://` or `https://`). If the protocol is not present, Twitter will not add a link.

```
// maybe something like this?
window.open(
    "http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=An%20Awesome%20Link&url=" + 
    ((htmlpath.substr(0,4) == 'http')?htmlpath:'http://' + htmlpath)
);
```